# Translation of Scottish 16th century church stained glass

Tags: latin-to-english-translation, inscription, paleography

[image: Culdees castle church]

This piece of stained glass (about 500mm x 400mm) is in our house but came from our adjoining castle.  I think it came from a since ruined church on the same site.  Anyone know what it means?

Answer (score 8):

The heraldry makes play on **ACRE** (plough and barley brew) and **HACKER** (with the bladed instrument above the plough and the halberd). Such visual puns are called Canting Heraldry as the [Heraldry Society](https://theheraldrysociety.com/class/canting-arms) explains. (Thanks! to TRiG)

The latinised name below the heraldry simply reads

> Marci Ackerman (?Ackermani) **:** 1561

"Of Mark Ackerman : 1561"
The words are in the possessive case to indicate whose window (or whose castle, or room).

Comment: Isn't it _Marti_? The letter is very different from the 'c' in _Ackerman_.

Comment: @Colin Fine , That's possible, since Mark and Marty are currently family names for Ackermans.